# Pandas assign column values from values of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df as below, in which I want to get `up_time` & `down_time`, which would come from different file. The file name is based on the column `File_name`. Based on this, I want Python to open the file, filter the new df based on time & get the corresponding `Up_time` & `Down_time`.

```
df

Time             Price  File_name  Up_Time  Down_Time
21-03-24 08:25  1037.3   45372      
21-03-24 08:26  1056.35  45375
21-03-24 08:27  1073.85  4537
```

I am using this code:

```
df['Up_Time'] = np.nan
df['Down_time'] = np.nan

for i in range(1, len(df) + 1):
    time=df.iloc[i]['Time']
    file_name=df.iloc[i]['File_name']
    new_df=pd.read_csv(path+str(file_name)+".csv")
    new_df=new_df[new_df['Time'].str.contains(time)]
    up_time=new_df['Up_Time']
    down_time=new_df['Down_Time']
    df.iloc[i]['Up_Time'] = up_time
    df.iloc[i]['Down_time'] = down_time
```

I get an error

> IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

or everywhere it is showing NaN

Not sure what the mistake is.

Comment: I think your index should start at 0  and got to len(df)

Comment: I am getting NaN in all the values.

Comment: You need to `merge` the two dataframes on column Filename

Comment: just pd.merge() them on filename column value

Comment: Column File_name is the name of the file. Like that I have multiple files to open & get the value. e.g. for row 2 I will open file naming "45375.csv" & get the up_time & down_time

Comment: Give a sample of your second df

Answer (score 0):

By converting the cell value to str i can then put that value in the original DF

```
up=str(new_df['Up_Time'])
up=up.replace('\nName: Up_Time, dtype: object', '')
up=up.replace('0    ', '')
up=up.replace('2024-03-21', '')
down=str(new_df['Down_Time'])
down=down.replace('\nName: Down_Time, dtype: object', '')
down=down.replace('0    ', '')
df.loc[df.index[i], 'Up_Time'] = up
df.loc[df.index[i], 'Down_Time'] = down
```